# MediaElement doesn't show video in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, video

So I am trying to add a video background to my WPF application.

For starters I tried to simply replace my photo to a video in the XAML using the code

```
 <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Page2.png"  />
 </Grid.Background>
```

But it failed of course, because `ImageBrush` doesn't supports video files.

I then proceed to try using `MediaElement`:

```
<MediaElement Source="MyFile.mp4"/>
```

and although I see the video perfectly on the design, when I am running the application, I am getting a blank screen.

Here is what I had already tried:

1. Changing Copy To Output property to "Always Copy".
2. Creating the video in multiple formats: .mov, .wmv, .mp4
3. Trying multiple videos. Their length are 3 minutes or so and 6 minutes or so.
4. Trying placing a video on a clean window, just to make sure I am not doing something silly with the XAML.

All to no avail.

What video formats are supported? Is there any size limit? Is there any time limit to the videos I wish to play? Are there more ways to show the video besides MediaElement ?

It's worth mentioning I am not fetching the videos from the internet, nor giving the user the option to select them and I hard copy the videos to the SAME directory of the window (If that makes any difference).

Any help, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Edit:
Now it works :D Here is what I had done:
1. Copy the video BOTH to the main directory of the project by right clicking on the name of the project->Add->Existing Item...->All files->selecting the video. and to the folder in which the XAML is located.

2. On both files I set Copy To Output property to "Always Copy" and Build Action to: "Content".
3. These steps allowed me to make a MediaElement, specifying ONLY the name of the file so I can run the application properly on any device.

Comment: There's not enough context in your question. It lacks anything even approximating a good [mcve] that would reliably reproduce the problem. That said, given that it works fine in the Designer, I would guess that the most likely reason for the problem is simply that you are specifying a plain file name without a full path, and the current directory is different when working in the designer than when actually running the program, so it can't find the file in the latter case. If you have the file in your .sln, maybe you just need to set it to "Content" and "Copy if newer" or "Copy always".

Comment: Well it should work cuz i just tried this. make sure (1) Include video in your project or Resources Folder (2) In video Properties set `Build Action = None` it should be none Ok and (3) `Copy To Output property to "Always Copy"` or `Copy To Output property to "Copy If newer"` and include video in your XAML like this `<MediaElement Source="Resources/MyFile.mkv" Width="300" Height="300" LoadedBehavior="Play"/>`

Comment: as you can notice i used `LoadedBehavior="Play"` to autoPlay video at startup and `.mkv` is the extension of video. so it's pretty much working with many formats of videos.

Comment: and i loaded a whole movie as media element so i don't think there is any size or time limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MediaElement not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007911/mediaelement-not-displaying)

Comment: Hi @RaoHammasHussain Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Along with your steps, and specifying the full path, I managed to show the video. My concern however is that the path I specified seems to be local, and on other computers might not work. Is there a way to specify a generic path, to the video file I included with my program? Many thanks!

Comment: No you don't need to do anything. by doing above steps the video will always be included in your project and it will be available everywhere. The path you are specifying is  not local but of your project.

Comment: but if you want user to pick the video to be played of their choice then obviously that's a different scenario and you'll have to follow some other approach for that purpose.

Comment: if you go in `Debug` folder you'll see `Resource` folder created there automatically and same video to be copied there.

Comment: I don't seem to have a Debug folder neither a resources one.

Comment: I managed to make it work!

Comment: @CUCUMBER Hey! Could you please share how you did it? I am stuck and would really appreciate some help! :)

Comment: @Fisheer, I haven't touched this technology for two years or so, have you tried Rao Arman's solution?

Comment: @CUCUMBER Hello! I solved it luckily ^^ I tried every possible solution but nothing worked, then I just put a . in front of the path to my source and it worked like a charm. So simple that I dismissed that solution first time I thought about it